# Demographic Analysis across multiple zip codes/area

Tags: data-visualization, multivariate-analysis

I am trying to analyze demographic information across 10 main zip codes that surround my area of interest.  How would I be able to compile the information I have to give me the demographics of the combined areas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to provide more information regarding the format of your data. Is it in .csv files or in shapefiles (i.e., shp)? Shapefiles may require specialized software in order to modify. No matter what your file format you will need to define variables of interest for the zip codes and make sure that you produce a categorical variable containing the zip code value.

Also, some more information regarding what you want to analyze will be helpful. This may determine how you organize your input data file for analysis. The statistical package will also matter.

[Wooldridge (2009)](http://www.worldcat.org/title/introductory-econometrics-a-modern-approach/oclc/269302901) has a good chapter (ch. 19) for preparing for an econometric analysis project that you may want to review.

Comment: The current data is in excel,  I have the data I want to review in each cell, however it is separated and I cannot determine how to put it together for a "big picture" capture.  I am looking at values such as population, household income, age...

Comment: So are you interested in summary statistics or is there a specific research question that you want to answer? Various statistical models are employed to answer a research question founded on a null and alternate hypothesis. For preparing your data you will want to create a ZIPCODE column in each excel spreadsheet and enter the zipcode value for each. Make sure that you standardize variable names (e.g., population, household income, age, etc.) in each excel spreadsheet if not already set up this way. Combine them by copying and pasting into a new excel spreadsheet.